# PHP max() and min() weird behavior with different types

Tags: php, comparison

I have been scratching my head for the past two hours over this behavior:

```
echo 'max(1, "a", "2"   ) : '; var_dump( max( 1, 'a', '2' ) );
echo 'max(1, "2", "a"   ) : '; var_dump( max( 1, '2', 'a' ) );
echo 'max(   "a", "2", 1) : '; var_dump( max( 'a', '2', 1 ) );
echo 'max(   "2", "a", 1) : '; var_dump( max( '2', 'a', 1 ) );
echo "\n";
echo 'min(1, "a", "2"   ) : '; var_dump( min( 1, 'a', '2' ) );
echo 'min(1, "2", "a"   ) : '; var_dump( min( 1, '2', 'a' ) );
echo 'min(   "a", "2", 1) : '; var_dump( min( 'a', '2', 1 ) );
echo 'min(   "2", "a", 1) : '; var_dump( min( '2', 'a', 1 ) );
```

Which prints out:

```
max(1, "a", "2"   ) : string(1) "2"
max(1, "2", "a"   ) : string(1) "a"
max(   "a", "2", 1) : int(1)
max(   "2", "a", 1) : int(1)

min(1, "a", "2"   ) : string(1) "2"
min(1, "2", "a"   ) : string(1) "a"
min(   "a", "2", 1) : int(1)
min(   "2", "a", 1) : int(1)
```

When I was expecting:

```
max(1, "a", "2"   ) : string(1) "2"
max(1, "2", "a"   ) : string(1) "2"
max(   "a", "2", 1) : string(1) "2"
max(   "2", "a", 1) : string(1) "2"

min(1, "a", "2"   ) : string(1) "a"
min(1, "2", "a"   ) : string(1) "a"
min(   "a", "2", 1) : string(1) "a"
min(   "2", "a", 1) : string(1) "a"
```

Note that the values given to `max()` and `min()` functions are always the same, but the order is different.

Also, according to the documentation, strings not started with numerical characters are evaluated as integer `0` when compared to integers, but multiple string values are compared alphanumerically. Source:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php

How could this output be explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparison in [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) is done sequentially as this can be seen in the source code:

[`min()` source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9af7ad0778eaf35993d66796a09d28ced98e1556/ext/standard/array.c#L1317):

```
//...
min = &args[0];

for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    is_smaller_function(&result, &args[i], min);
    if (Z_TYPE(result) == IS_TRUE) {
        min = &args[i];
    }
}
//...
```

[`max()` source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/9af7ad0778eaf35993d66796a09d28ced98e1556/ext/standard/array.c#L1364):

```
//...
max = &args[0];

for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
    is_smaller_or_equal_function(&result, &args[i], max);
    if (Z_TYPE(result) == IS_FALSE) {
        max = &args[i];
    }
}
//...
```

So you can see that the function goes through the array and checks if the next value is smaller/bigger than the previous smallest/biggest saved value.

---

To understand how you get these results you also have to know that the comparison of the values is done after [PHP type juggling.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

So let's look at two example to see how the functions work:

#### Example 1

```
max ( 1 , 'a' , '2' )
      │    │     │
      1 > 'a'    │
        │        │
        1    <  '2'
             │
             └ Result: '2'
```

1. Comparing `1` and `'a'`, numerical context means `'a'` gets converted to `0`, `1` is greater than `0`.
   **→ int `1` returned**
2. Comparing `1` and `'2'`, numerical string means `'2'` gets converted to `2`, `2` is greater than `1`.
   **→ string `'2'` returned**

- **Result: string '2'**

#### Example 2

```
max ( 1 , '2' , 'a' )
      │    │     │
      1 < '2'    │
        │        │
       '2'   <  'a'
             │
             └ Result: 'a'
```

1. Comparing `1` and `'2'`, numerical string means `'2'` gets converted to `2`, `2` is greater than `1`.
   **→ string `'2'` returned**
2. Comparing `'2'` and `'a'`, both strings means string comparison, `'a'` is greater than `'2'` just compared with the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/).
   **→ string `'a'` returned**

- **Result: string 'a'**

And the same rules apply for all of the other examples.

Comment: This answer makes sense and I feel relieved, but where is stated that comparison is done sequentially? It seems that PHP documentation is lacking this information.

Comment: @AndréAntunesdaCunha You can derive from some examples that it is sequentially, but it really isn't clearly written in the manual that way.

Comment: @u_mulder You shouldn't link to source code lines to **master** branch, since the code will evolve and lines wouldn't be accurate anymore. Link to a commit hash instead for example.

Comment: My answer is living it's own life o_O)))